# removeFromSuperview function doesn't work fine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have six imageviews and I set them like this :

```
img1 img2 img3 img4 img5 img6
```

but when I remove `img1` by using `removeFromSuperview` function other imageviews doesn't appear find. for example if I removed `img1`, other imageviews appear on each other:

```
img23456
```

I don't want to use `hide` functions, because a space between them will be appear. for example if I remove `img1` :

```
'  ' img2 img3 img3 img4 img5 img6
```

on other hand, what I want is if `img1` removed (without first space):

```
img2 img3 img3 img4 img5 img6
```

my layout:

[image]

**updated**

my code:

```
    if(self.job.wifi == "1")
    {
                    self.img_option_1.isHidden = false
        self.img_option_1.image = UIImage(named: "wififree")

    }else{
        self.img_option_1.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    if(self.job.apple_health == "1")
    {
        self.img_option_2.isHidden = false
        self.img_option_2.image = UIImage(named: "sib_noghrei")
    }else{
       // self.img_option_2.removeFromSuperview()
        self.img_option_2.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    if(self.job.wc == "1")
    {

        self.img_option_3.isHidden = false
        self.img_option_3.image = UIImage(named: "wc")
    }else{
        self.img_option_3.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    if(self.job.full_time == "1")
    {
        self.img_option_4.isHidden = false
        self.img_option_4.image = UIImage(named: "fulltime")
    }else{
        self.img_option_4.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    if(self.job.pos == "1")
    {

        self.img_option_5.isHidden = false
        self.img_option_5.image = UIImage(named: "pos")
    }else{
        self.img_option_5.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    if(self.job.parking == "1")
    {
        self.img_option_6.isHidden = false
        self.img_option_6.image = UIImage(named: "parking")
    }else{
        self.img_option_6.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: What language is this, Swift? How did you add 6 UIImageViews like this: img1 img2 img3 img4 img5 img6 ? If I type that in Swift do I add 6 UIImageViews like that?

Comment: my language is `swift `.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian To make it easier to help you and understand what you are doing, add your code instead of img 1 img 2 img 3 img 4... As of now, I think nobody will understand what you are trying to do and what the problem is. Maybe you can add images too what is happening with the UI.

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is, If you remove **img1** `UIImageView`  from your superView. Your constraints on the rest of the `UIImageViews` that are connected to the one you removed will fail, because they are connected to **img1** `UIImageView` .

**Hard solution:** You need to update/connect/add your constraints for every `UIImageView` , when you are removing something in the "chain" from superView by code.

## **Better solution:** (Best practice)

Remove all your `UIImageViews` and add a single `UICollectionView`.

Add one `UIImageView` to the cell, and simply `delete` or `add` cells as you wish, and the `UICollectionView` will **handle all the layout for you**.

Comment: Even better solution (and actual best practice), use `UIStackView` which is easier to use for static content.

Comment: As how to how to do it quickly : Remove all constraints on your image views, select all imageViews, and do Editor -> Embed In -> Stack View

Comment: @deadbeef Great to add another option as UIStackView. However, UIStackView supports **iOS 9.0** > , therefore:, calling something ""actual best practice" that only supports 1 version back in history is **not a good practice** neither. It's called an option.

Comment: Sorry for the bad english, by actual I rather meant nowadays. Also, I doubt that an iOS beginner will support iOS 8. At the very least I would not recommend it.

Comment: @Deadbeef Tell that to Facebook, Snapchat or any other wide spread App. its more than 5% of the people still using 8+. That is 1 in 20 people. When it comes to "poor" countries where they can't afford the latest devices, I would say **it's more** than 1 in 20 people (5%) of the total users. Don't compare a UICollectionView to UIStackView. It's 2 **completely** different components. To say that "I don't recommend using a UICollectionView, but use a UIStackView instead" does not make any real sense. In the end it all comes down to what u want as a developer from each **different** component.

Comment: @deadbeef However, you should add that as an answer so people can see the option, I will upvote you when you do.

Answer (score 0):

@sneak's answer is the standard way to solve this problem.

I have one more idea to share, which I used in my app.

Make the `spacing` `constraints` as the `multiplied` `constant` of the immediate left `UIImageView`.

Then take the `IBOutlet` of the `width` `constraint` of img's . Then change your else part like this ->

```
else{
       widthImg1.constant = 0
}
```

Now the spacing will also become zero because it's a multiplied constant.

Comment: I had 2 solutions in my answer, and updating constraints was one of them :) However. good work that you gave a detailed example and solution by code and explanation for it! Will upvote you for that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will keep in mind my answer's quality in future.